# Homepage Changes Based on Who is Accessing It

Tags: accessibility, hyperlinks, users, homepage

I am redesigning a homepage which has 10 places it can take you.  Four types of people will be using this homepage.

Person 1 can access elements 1, 2, and 3.
Person 2 can access elements 3, and 4.
Person 3 can access elements 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9.
Person 4 can access all elements.

Instead of having a user click a link just for it to say "You do not have access to this page.", my plan was to not even have that option show up in the first place.

I am trying to think of a good way to present this page in a consistent manner.  While for one user, they only need to see 2 options, another user will need to see 10 options.

Currently, there is just a grid of buttons leading to the links.  It is not great.  One thing I was thinking of is to put all relevant information on the homepage based on the user, and to have a toolbar at the top directing to each section.  However, this could present a problem because of the data inside the links.  How can I present the respective links to the users in a consistent manner?  I want Person 4 to be able to hop on Person 2's computer without skipping a beat.

This is the design I ended up going with.  It is a menu at the top of the page.  (Sorry about poor wireframe...I'm new to that tool.)  Are there issues with this design?:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsY2o3.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Do you have a sketch or wireframe? What else appears on the home page? Do the nav links need to appear on the top bar or in the body of the home page?

Comment: Re. this: " I want Person 4 to be able to hop on Person 2's computer without skipping a beat." how will the computer/app recognise the user?

Comment: @DarrylGodden that is backend logic.  I've got that covered, thanks.

Comment: ? So if someone walks away from a computer, then someone else sits down, the computer knows who they are?

Comment: @DarrylGodden Haha.  For arguments sake, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information you're providing isn't very descriptive of the complete scenario, but based on it, it sounds like you're describing a situation where you have users and a superuser or admin. If this is the case, it's quite common to display only the available options for their level of access.

This being said, you have two choices here: if you don't care about people to know about the existence of different sections (or access those sections), then you should display only the available options for them and nothing else. This is pretty common in administrative, legal or business scenarios.

However, if you want these users with limited access to access other levels based on certain conditions (upgrades, upsales or whatever) then you may display ALL available sections, only that grayed out (or opacity down) or with an icon that shows the need for an upgrade. However, do not leave it just grayed : you should have some action, such as a dialog with a CTA inviting the user to upgrade to access that section. Otherwise, the links need to have a clear message like "only available to X level"

As for layout, it's impossible to tell with your information, it could be test links, cards, grids or whatever

Answer (score -1):

Are you asking for a technical or UX solution here?

UPDATE:
Very curious why someone has voted this question down. The question appears to be one a UX-sided one, however, it is really not clear. Esp. because a technical solution would be very simple.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: Cannot comment below 50 points, monsieur.

Comment: Simple answer is to build up rep, and this is a comment - not an answer.

Comment: In regards to your update, I voted it down.  It is not an answer.  I understand that you cannot comment, but that is by design.  You do not yet have the right to comment.  You must earn it.  In the meanwhile, you have to earn rep.